# What is causing "unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'list' and 'int'"?

Tags: python

This is the code I have right now. I'm trying to apply a radix sort to a list of numbers read from a file and write the sorted list to a different file.

```py
from math import log

b = open("radix.in.txt").readlines()
a = [int(i) for i in b]

f = open("radix.out.txt", "w")
def getIndex(num, base, digit_num):
    return (num // base ** digit_num) % base  

def newLists(size):
    return [ [] for i in range(size) ]  

def order(a, base, digit_num):
    placehold = newLists(base)
    for num in a:
        placehold[getIndex(num, base, digit_num)].append(num)  
    return placehold

def radixSort(a, base):
    passes = 3
    new_list = a
    for digit_num in range(passes):
        new_list = order(new_list, base, digit_num)
    list_c = [str(i) for i in new_list]
    print list_c

radixSort(a, 10)
```

The input file is just a list of all the numbers to sort with one number on each line

The traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 23, in radixSort new_list = order(new_list, base, digit_num) 
File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 16, in order placehold[getIndex(num, base, digit_num)].append(num) 
File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 8, in getIndex return (num // base ** digit_num) % base 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: Your traceback please? Your input file please?

Comment: `return (num // base ** digit_num) % base` this line, because num is a list and python doesn't know how to do `//` with a list

Comment: The traceback:
  File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 23, in radixSort
    new_list = order(new_list, base, digit_num)
  File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 16, in order
    placehold[getIndex(num, base, digit_num)].append(num)
  File "C:\Users\Nolan Caldwell\Desktop\HW5.py", line 8, in getIndex
    return (num // base ** digit_num) % base
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'list' and 'int'


The input file is just a list of all the numbers to sort with one number on each line

Comment: Try setting `passes = 1` in your `radixSort` and see what is printed. You will find that it is a list of lists (as @bereal has pointed out)

Comment: Not directly related, but `newLists(size)` would more usually be written like `return [[]] * size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `order()` expects a list of integers as a first argument `a`, and that's what passed in the first iteration.

However, `order()` returns a list of lists, and that new list is passed instead of `a` in the second iteration in `radixSort()`, that's why it fails.

Comment: Thank you this helped to fix the problem. I also had to change "size" to "base".